# Unable to download edge browser on Google Chrome VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, rdp

I created a RDP Virtual Machine on Google Cloud Platform as per this doc https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-windows-compute-engine
However I am unable to download edge on this VM. I want to setup a VM which I can use it as my laptop without any restrictions.
Please advise.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about "I am unable to download edge on this VM"?

Comment: Hi Serhii, See I am able to access the RDP and launch Chrome browser. But I want to launch Edge and Firefox browsers as well. I am able to go to the download page to install edge, but then nothing happens. It doesn't get downloaded and the installation doesn't start. I guess this VM is set up only to launch Google Chrome and can not install any other applications on it. Please let me know what other details do you want.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? There's no way to prevent VM from launching particular software.

Comment: I am using Windows 2019 server. I configured the VM as explained in this document https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-windows-compute-engine  I guess Google is preventing to download Edge from Chrome. Because when I start the download I get a message syaing You will need an app to use this app. And the download doesn't start.

Comment: Have you tried to download Edge through the default windows browser? Have you tried to copy Edge package to your VM instead of downloading it?